# how do I update/delete a content in Django?

Tags: django, crud

So I have a form in Django that lets users write their diary. 
Now I want to add edit button and delete button, but I'm having error. So here are the codes.
template (detail.html)

```
...
<form method='post' class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <a href="{% url 'delete' authuser_id slug %}">
            <button class='btn btn-primary button-delete'>Delete</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('detail/<int:authuser_id>/<slug:slug>', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('detail/<int:authuser_id>/<slug:slug>', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import DiaryInput
...

def detail(request, authuser_id, slug):
    todayDiary = DiaryInput.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, '/detail.html', {'todayDiary' : todayDiary})

def delete(request, authuser_id, slug):
    todayDiary = DiaryInput.objects.get(slug=slug)
    todayDiary.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

When I go to the detail page of a specific diary, I get an error that says : 
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/detail/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/delete$'] 
I believe there is something wrong with my template, in the `{% url %}` tag, but I don't see what I've done wrong. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: as the error said, it tried with arguments '('',)', means it found no argument. Please make sure you are passing the context to template correctly. If you are still facing errors, then post the view codes for the form.

Comment: Please show main `urls.py` also always add `/` at the end of first argument of `path()`. Also remember adding `authuser_id` `slug` in template. (Could be through for-loop, we can't see how you are getting that).

Comment: @Hisham___Pak Thanks. I've tried ```<a href="{% url 'update' todayDiary.authuser_id todayDiary.slug %}"><button class='btn btn-primary button-update'>edit</button></a>``` But it keeps on saying ```Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/update/(?P<authuser_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']``` What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you check if this is even working? `todayDiary = DiaryInput.objects.get(slug=slug)` in detail view Try printing this variable and get result in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the same path for both the urls `detail` and `delete` so change there :

```
 path('detail/<int:authuser_id>/<slug:slug>', views.detail, name='detail'),
 path('delete/<int:authuser_id>/<slug:slug>', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

And now in the template

```
 <a href="{% url 'delete' todayDiary.id todayDiary.slug %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
views.py

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')             
    else:
        form = AddEntryForm()
    return render(request, '/add.html', {'form':form})

def update(request, id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditEntryForm(data=request.POST, instance=entry)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')             
    else:
        form = EditEntryForm(instance=entry)
    return render(request, '/edit.html', {'form':form})

def delete(request, id, slug):
    Entry.objects.filter(id=id, slug=slug).delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

```
urls.py

path('add_entry/', views.add, name='add'),
path('update/<int:id>/', views.update, name='update'),    
path('delete/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' todayDiary.authuser_id todayDiary.slug %}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
<a href="{% url 'update' todayDiary.authuser_id %}">Update</a>
<a href="{% url 'delete' todayDiary.authuser_id todayDiary.slug %}">Delete</a>
```

and render form in templates as {{ form.as_p }} and it's good idea to seprate path for detail and delete don't mix it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. In the template, wouldn't I need ```todayDiary.slug``` in the second line? (Update part)

Comment: actually in update view I I'm getting entry by id only so I won't need but if you want to get 
entry by slug too then you have to add in url + a tags for update links